# .htaccess rewrite rule redirect to 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a few folders such as `php_includes` `templates` and a few others and I am adding a `.htaccess` file for them all. So far what I have works if the user trys to directly access the file in the address bar, but I'd rather it send it to a 404 page.

```
IndexIgnore *
# no one gets in here!
deny from all
#error 404
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

Is there something wrong with my `.htaccess` All I feel like is happening is the deny from all is taking over so the 404 won't work directly. Though I've tried this with a different `.htaccess` file for the main site, and the 404 isn't working in there either.

Same `ErrorDocument` as the others but here is how my directory is set up

```
  -.htaccess
 --public_html
   --error
     --404.html
 --admin
```

So maybe I am either getting the `ErrorDocument` incorrect for my `.htaccess` that or I have the path directory incorrect. Can someone please explain what the issue here is?

*note* I am using `000webhost` if that matters sometimes I see them doing some silly stuff, and this is just a testing server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `deny` directive it sends error code `403`.

Declare your custom handler for `403`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/404.html
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out for sure. I need to learn my Error Codes :)

Comment: Hey anubhava. Since my test directory is three stages in should I change the 403 ErrorDocument to something like `../../../error/404.html`

Comment: Nevermind, it's my HTML page's fault. It's using absolute paths instead of relative paths. My fault. Thanks you are a kind friend.

Answer (score 0):

The deny from all directive will generate a 403 error.
So just do this

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/404.html
```